# Display by customer generated product collection with category layout

Tags: magento-1.8, product-collection

I'm trying to generate a search result/category page with a custom product collection. The plan is to create the product collection based on attributes the customer can choose in a custom html form. I have an **IndexController**

```
public function indexAction() {
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->renderLayout();
}

public function postAction() {
    $postData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
    $productCollection = Mage::getModel('mymodule/api')->checkPost($postData);
    //$this->_redirect(???);
}
```

which is receiving postData from my form.phtml and passing it to my checkPost function (postData gets evaluated) which returns a custom productCollection. I would like to redirect the customer from the form to a category/search result page with the productCollection as results but I have no idea how to get this done.

Comment: I know this is not part of the question, but why did you use a POST instead of a GET?

Comment: GET is actually suitable for search results as it allows user the share the link of the search result instead of doing the search it all over again.

Comment: Hm I guess the main reason is that I'm at the very beginning of programming web applications... Thanks for pointing that out, I'll check it out.

Answer (score 1):

You can not send a product collection between page requests, this would mean storing it in a session but sessions only work well for simple values.

You can load the blocks that Magento uses to display search results and add the collection to those. So add the `catalog/product/list.phtml` like it is done in the `catalog.xml` for example and add the following to your controller. However, I would use GET variables instead of POST for practical reasons

```
public function postAction() {
    $postData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
    $productCollection = Mage::getModel('mymodule/api')->checkPost($postData);

    $this->loadLayout();

    $this->getLayout()->getBlock('product_list')->setCollection(productCollection);

    $this->renderLayout();
}
```

**Side note:** From the functionality you're describing I think Magento's native Advanced Search should fit your needs tho. Check out [this post](http://www.magetraining.co.uk/blog/how-to-set-up-advanced-search-in-magento/) on how to set it up.

Comment: This looks promising! I'll update here as soon as I figured everything out. Thanks alot. Btw. yes, Advanced Search is actually really similiar to what I have in mind, the only difference is that I want to give much more customisation (for the admin) on how attributes affect each other.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use a GET request for that action. That way, you can directly display what you want using the collection (assuming that you are going to redirect for displaying the collection)